# having trouble with java programming and toString()

Tags: java

Okay, so I am completely new to all this Java programming stuff, and my knowledge of it is very little, but for my work, I am to:

> Create a class that represents a rectangle. A rectangle is specified
>   by the coordinates (x, y) of its top-left corner and its width and
>   height. This class will be used to create many rectangle objects, and
>   it must feature
>
> - dynamic fields (variables) to store x, y, the width and height as fractional numbers;
> - a constructor with parameters that provide x, y, the width and height;
> - a function that returns the area of the rectangle;
> - a function that returns the length of the perimeter of the rectangle; and
> - a function that returns the string representation of the rectangle, the four numbers, within a pair of parenthesis, separated by commas
>     [this function must be named `toString()`]
>
> Write, in a separate class, a main method that accepts the four
>   numbers as command line arguments, instantiates a rectangle object,
>   and prints the string representation of the rectangle, the area, and
>   the perimeter.

so basically if it works, it should look like :

> java TestRect 1 2 3 4
>   rectangle = (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0)
>   area = 12.0
>   perimeter = 14.0

okay, sorry, for before, but umm, after reading your answers, ive made some changes, im still not entirely sure if this is what you guys mean, but:

i added

```
TestRect1 r = new TestRect1();
```

to TestRect (the main class)
 made the changes :

```
  System.out.println("rectangle = " + r.toString());
  System.out.println("area      = " + r.area(w, h));
  System.out.println("perimeter = " + r.perimeter(w, h));
```

to TestRect1 (the other class with all the formulas), and i got rid of the "static" stuff
and added :

```
   public double x;
   public double y;
   public double w;
   public double h;
```

so when i compile them, they both compile, no errors, but when it comes to actually running the program, where i type in

```
java TestRect 1 2 3 4
```

the error pops up saying:

```
javac: invalid flag: 1
usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

Comment: What's your question? I see requirements, I see code and a vague request for help, but I don't see a well thought out description of exactly what your problem is. Please consider taking a little time to give us the details of just where your stuck, of exactly what your current code is doing wrong, of what specific concepts confuse you...

Comment: my question is how to solve the question ? 
the question is the first part .. where it says all the stuff about the rectangle, and that you need to classes

the second part is the work i have done, but am now stuck

Comment: Again, what are you stuck on? What does your current code do? What does it not do? Please help us help you. We're not going to do your homework for you, but we'll be more than happy to clarify concepts so that you can learn to solve this yourself, but we need your help to do be able to this well. I'm asking you to think about your question and to put some effort into the question. Do this and it will pay out dividends for you in the end.

Comment: the problem for me is, it doesnt work, so it doesnt compile

Comment: If it doesn't compile, you should show us what errors you're getting.

Comment: The immediate problem is that there is no method `toString(double, double, double, double)` defined in class `TestRect`. Perhaps you just want to change the call in `main()` to be `TestRect1.toString(...)`. However, as several answers point out, while this might produce the correct output, it will not satisfy the other requirements of the assignment (constructor, etc.).

Comment: I think your error is ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: @user1615783 have you tried [something like this](http://pastie.org/private/pekhlzhogfgiotlzisq6kg)?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is homework we shouldn't give you the full answer. You've obviously learnt what a class is and what an instance of a class is.

Your current problem is that you are not actually creating an instance of a Rectangle class. What you have is a simple class with nothing but static methods.

So as a hint to get you on the right track:

You need a class that you can create an instance of like so:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x,y,width,height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to learn Java, i would refrain from posting the complete code. instead let me point out issues in your code.

1. You have not followed the first two instructions in your spec.

Declare member variables in the Class for x,y,width and height
Create a constructor which takes these 4 variables as arguments and assigns the class members to them

1. All the methods in the class can then be declared non-static and need not take any arguments because you have those variables stored as class members.

Answer (score 0):

Your `TestRect1` class is a little lacking.

- It should have four member fields representing x, y, width, and height.
- The `toString()` method should be an instance method (not a `static` method like you have) and it should take no arguments. It should construct the string from the field values.
- The `area()` and `perimeter()` methods should likewise be change to be instance methods and to take no parameters.

Then your `main()` method should be modified to construct a `TestRect1` object and use its methods and fields to do what it needs to do. For instance, once you have a `TestRect1` object, you can call its `toString()` method:

```
TestRect1 rect;
// initialize rect
System.out.println("rectangle = " + rect.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are a beginner so I would recommend that you should try to write with your own and if you feel any query then post your problems with your code so that it will be easy to understand. But by the way I'm just posting few parts of my solution.
First define a class called `Rectangle` inside this class write one constructor and three methods
1. `area(width,height)`
2. `perimeter(width,height)`
3. `@Override toString()` method and write like this.

```
public String toString()  
{  
      return "("+x+","+y+","+width+","+height+")";  
}
```

Take command line argument as `TestRect 1 2 3 4`
I would also recommend to look for previous answers. Hope this help you.